# How to intimate a Event to all the instances of Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have a Functions App which scales to a couple of hundred instances under peak load, now we need a way in which if a particular event happens (maybe a new message in the queue) all the instances are notified, what are the potential approaches to achieve this, please advise..

Comment: May I ask why you need this? Some state/cache to invalidate?

Comment: Do you mean something like is a CancellationToken?

Comment: @Mikhail yes, that is correct, if we get a special type of message we want the instance to reload the state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One pattern is to have a common marker (a blob) which changes when the common state if updated. Each instance can proactively check the blob's etag to determine if it has the state has changed, and if so, it knows to reload its state. 
Note that:

1. it's important for the instance to check (rather than wait for a change notification) because there can be a lag in most notification mechanisms. For example, a blob trigger could lag several minutes.
2. There's no way to bypass the load-balancer and send a message to a specific instance. So you can't proactively send an invalidation message.

Another pattern is to have you state fully externalized in something like Redis. That's easy to invalidate and update. (Although that's essentially just a special case of the prior suggestion)